# CSS: how to hover an element not immediatly next

Tags: html, css

I need to hover element `<a>` to show element `<d>`, but between `<a>` and `<d>` there is `<b>` and `<c>`. Possibly using just CSS.

This is the HTML code:

```
<a>Riferimenti bibliografici</a>
<b/>
<c>
<d>Oxford: Oxford University Press.</d>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please provide your clean code with proper explanation of what you actually need so we can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific use-case you have presented, the **general sibling combinator** `~` can be used - so long as the element in question *is a sibling element*.

> **General sibling combinator**
>
> The `~` combinator selects siblings. This means that the second
>   element follows the first (though not necessarily immediately), and
>   both share the same parent.
>  
>   **Syntax:** `A ~ B`
>   **Example:** `p ~ span` will match all `<span>` elements that follow a `<p>`.

[CSS selectors - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)

```css
a:hover ~ d {
  display: block;
}

d {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a>hover over to reveal element below</a>
<br>
<c></c>
<d>Oxford: Oxford University Press.</d>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="a">Hello</div>
<div class="b">Hi</div>
<div class="c">Whats'up</div>
<div class="d">Cool!</div>
```

CSS

```
.a:hover  ~ .d {opacity:1;}
.d {opacity:0;transition:1s;}
```

Checkout this [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXBVWv)